# LinqToDB How to use MapValueAttribute in DataParameter

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, enums, linq2db

I have enum 'EntityStatus' with MapValue:

```
public enum EntityStatus
{
    [MapValue("")]
    None,
    [MapValue("AR")]
    AwaitingReview,
    [MapValue("IR")]
    InReview,
    [MapValue("RT")]
    Returned,
    [MapValue("RS")]
    Resolved,
    [MapValue("AG")]
    Agreed       
}
```

When I call stored procedure by

```
DataBase.ExecuteProc("myStoredProcedureName",
                    new DataParameter("@EntityStatus", EntityStatus.Agreed));
```

I catch by a profiler call "EXEC myStoredProcedureName @EntityStatus = 5"

Me need @EntityStatus = 'AG'.

Is there a solution? How do I setup mapping by MapValue in DataParameter?

Comment: `ConvertTo<string>.From(EntityStatus.Agreed);` http://blog.linq2db.com/2015/05/using-mapvalueattribute-to-control.html

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Thanks a lot.